# Horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I have the following

**HTML:**

```
<div id="filter-menu">
    <div class="filter-item home selected"></div>
    <div class="filter-item animals"></div>
    <div class="filter-item ancient"></div>
    <div class="filter-item energy"></div>
    <div class="filter-item env"></div>
    <div class="filter-item travel"></div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS:**

```
#filter-menu{
    width: 505px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#filter-menu .filter-item{
    float: left;
    height: 38px;
    width: 84px;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

#filter-menu .selected{
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#filter-menu .home{
    background-image: url('images/Home.png');
    width: 78px;
}

#filter-menu .animals{
    background-image: url('images/Animals.png');
    width: 80px;
}

#filter-menu .ancient{
    background-image: url('images/Ancient.png');
    width: 80px;
}

#filter-menu .energy{
    background-image: url('images/Energy.png');
    width: 79px;
}

#filter-menu .env{
    background-image: url('images/Environment.png');
    width: 85px;
}

#filter-menu .travel{
    background-image: url('images/Travel.png');
    width: 79px;
}
```

---

1. The first menu item should not have any distance between left border.
2. And the last item should not have any distance between right border.
3. The distance between menu items should be chosen automatically.

pic:
[image]
Please, help to rewrite css rules. Because in this way the distance sets manually and the last element doesn't stick to right border.

Comment: To be fair, this is a **very** bad way to build a menu. You are *not* putting any text in your menu items so screenreaders won't be able to read the menu. On top of that you are using a different image for all your items, which will definitely cause overhead. At least put them all in a CSS Sprite (Google it). You are *not* using a `<ul>` - which you should. Tips: First get your HTML structure as a menu should be with an optional nav tag: ´<nav><ul><li></li></ul></nav>`. Then just use modern CSS to get what you want. Gradients and triangles are possible with CSS.

Comment: I'm not writing your code. But you should use `<ul>` and `<li>` for the list. Then you set specific rules to `:first` and `:last` on the  `<li>` for the margins on the sides

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend you to do that.. Instead create centered menu.. Stretching menu isn't good..

But there is one alternative way of doing that.. Use tables..

```
 #nav {
    display: table;
    height: 87px;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 87px;

    line-height: 87px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Here is a demo.. You can customize it accordingly..
http://jsfiddle.net/eCPSh/647/